# Need to bring a windows application(Excel in my case) to foreground - python

Tags: python, windows, automation

I am creating a windows automation script. I need to bring Excel application to foreground. I am able to open excel application and get list of subprocess running. But i am not sure how to Excel application to foreground. Please help

```
import subprocess
from win32com.client import Dispatch

xl = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True 

cmd = 'WMIC PROCESS get Caption,Commandline,Processid'
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in proc.stdout:
    print(line)
```

I am getting list of applications open, but i need to bring Excel to foreground. Please help me how to do it.

> b'EXCEL.EXE                         "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE"
>   b'SearchFilterHost.exe                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           740        \r\r\n'
>   b'python.exe                        C:\Users\arvin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                \r\r\n'
>   b'conhost.exe                       \??\C:\WINDOWS\system32\conhost.exe 0x4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      15724      \r\r\n'
>   b'cmd.exe                           C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c "WMIC PROCESS get Caption,Commandline,Processid"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              18084      \r\r\n'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using all Microsoft Office applications, chances are **object.Activate()** method will work.  This is part of Microsoft VBA and C# application calls that are also available to 3rd party languages.  Code below was tested on my Windows 10 environment, python 3.7 with pywin32, and MS-Office 2013.

```
####### Activate one excel file ##############
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb1 = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\python\so\sheet1.xlsx')
wb2 = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\python\so\sheet2.xlsx')
wb3 = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\python\so\sheet3.xlsx')    
excel.Visible = True

# This will open 3 workbooks with wb1 on top.

excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name
# Prints name of currently active workbook, i.e., the one on top.

wb3.Activate()  # puts workbook3 on top
wb2.Activate()  # puts workbook2 on top

### You may need to install pywin32.
### pip install pywin32
```

Comment: I tried this answer, but with excel already open, I was not able to open a new workbook. I have to send a click event to the initial excel to get a subsequent workbook to open. This could be a COM issue on my side though, as I am working with COM AddIns

Comment: Sorry for your trouble. If you already have an excel file open before loading the Python library to control excel (win32) and defining new workbook objects (wb1 to wb3), the Python library may not know about that excel file.  After loading win32, try to see if you can close all pre-existing excel files.  Try ```excel.ActiveWorkbook.Close()```.  Then proceed as above.

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to bring the excel window to foreground you can do this:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
from win32gui import SetForegroundWindow

xl = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True
SetForegroundWindow(xl.hwnd)
```

Where hwnd is the excel's window id. [More information about hwnd](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a25a604b-d92d-434a-a0f4-5da0180be41b/definition-of-window-handle?forum=winforms)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else also stumbles across this post and is looking for a solution for Microsoft Word (works slightly differently than Excel):

```
import win32com.client
import win32gui
import time

word = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Word.Application")
word.Visible = True
word.Documents.Open(r'C:\Temp\myDocument.docx', ReadOnly=True)

win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(word.ActiveWindow.Hwnd)
print('Click another window in the foreground, Word will regain focus in 10s.')
time.sleep(10)
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(word.ActiveWindow.Hwnd)
print('Click another window in the foreground, Word will regain focus in 10s.')
time.sleep(10)
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(word.ActiveWindow.Hwnd)
```